# When loading a custom form on SP list, the same record is loading every time (new or edit form)?

Tags: sharepoint-online

When loading a custom form on SP list, the same record is loading every time (new or edit form). I have tried adding refresh and reset form on everything. The list is very simple, not too many columns, no lookups etc.
It's not recognising the record that has been selected for some reason? It was working fine and i published a change last week and now isn't working. Please can someone assist?

Comment: Are you customizing the list form using power apps? What is the formula you used for "item" property of form control?

Comment: it says this: If(IsBlank(SharePointIntegration.Selected) || IsEmpty(SharePointIntegration.Selected),First(Rentals),SharePointIntegration.Selected)

Comment: what about the OnSuccess property ?

Comment: On SharePointIntegration properties, can you share the value of the following properties : OnEdit, OnNew, OnCancel,